# Regex pattern that matches all forms of integer literals

Tags: regex, perl, swift

I need a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) pattern that matches all forms of literals in the [Swift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift_%28Apple_programming_language%29) (particularly integer) language (including **binary** , **octal**, **decimal** and **hexadecimal** literals).

So far I got

```
/-?\d+(\.\d+)?/
```

which I think matches integers and decimals. But I am not sure about how to write it for binary, octal and hexadecimal. I need only one pattern that matches all.

For hexadecimal, the `/[0-9a-fA-F]+/` pattern would work. But I want a single pattern that matches all integer literals including binary, octal, decimal and hexadecimal literals.

Comment: `But I am not sure about how to write it for binary, octal and hexadecimal.` Post some examples which replicate this.

Comment: `^(?:0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+|-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$` would works for all but except octal.

Comment: `/-?\d+(.\d+)?/` This would match floating point numbers.

Comment: Thanks Avinash. I changed your expression to (?:[0-9a-fA-F]+|-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?) since hexadecimal number can be 9F as well. But I didnot understand the meanding of (?: in the beginning and before decimal.

Comment: `(?: .... )` is a capture group like `()` only it doesn't save it in a variable, `$1`, `$2`, etc (so it doesn't capture anything). You use it just like normal parenthesis so you can do `or` with `|` and stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use Test::Simple;

my $pat = qr/^(?:
  [0-9][0-9_]* |
  0b[01][01_]* |
  0o[0-7][0-7_]* |
  0x[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F_]*
)$/x;

my @oks = (
    "1",
    "01",
    "1__",
    "0b101",
    "0b0101__101",
    "0o2242",
    "0o224__2_",
    "0x2df1",
    "0x2D_f1_",
);

my @ngs = (
    "1.0",
    "_1",
    "1e23",
    "1_e23_",
    "0b12",
    "0o12f",
    "0o12e1",
    "0_o2",
    "0x01d1p1",
    "0O1",
    "0X1",
    "0B1",
);

for my $val (@oks) {
    ok($val =~ $pat, "match: $val");
}
for my $val (@ngs) {
    ok(($val !~ $pat), "reject: $val");
}
```

Because the unary operator, `-`, is not a part of integer literal, I did not include it. See [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_487) or [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/LexicalStructure.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH30-XID_907).

Note that, this is for **integer** only, not including **float** types.

If you want all numeric types, the pattern would be:

```
my $pattern = qr/^(?:
  [0-9][0-9_]* (?: \.[0-9][0-9_]*)? (?: [eE][\+\-]?[0-9][0-9_]*)? |
  0b[01][01_]* |
  0o[0-7][0-7_]* |
  0x[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F_]* (?: \.[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F_][pP][\+\-]?[0-9][0-9_]* | [pP][\+\-]?[0-9][0-9_]* )?
)$/x;
```